# Native stack traces from Firebase Crashlytics on Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-ndk, stack-trace, crashlytics

Our Android app has a native (NDK built) shared object. How can I use Firebase Crashlytics to get symbolicated stack traces?

Note that the release build of our app deliberately strips the shared object so we'd need a way to provide the unstripped binary.

Related question. Is there any way to get the raw crash report out of Crashltyics. The UI gives us a restricted view. If I had the raw stack trace then I could at least manually figure out what method the app is crashing in.

This is pretty crucial for us. Without native support Crashlytics has limited value. Seems like a fairly critical oversight so I'm hoping the oversight is mine and not Google's.